# 'seems + noun' vs 'seems like + noun'

Tags: linking-verbs

What are the similarities and differences? Presented in https://english.stackexchange.com/a/11324/50720,  [*Corpus of Contemporary English*](http://www.americancorpus.org) depicts the dominance of 'seems like', but what does this imply?

Are there any formal terms describing these issues? I read that ['to seem' is a copular verb](http://www.englishgrammar.org/preposition-conjunction/).

Comment: Obiter dictum: I also read http://english.stackexchange.com/q/97541/50720 but it seems noncontextual here.

Comment: I'm looking for a specific question here. Some examples would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One uses  "seems _ARTICLE _NOUN", "seems to be _ARTICLE _NOUN", and  "seems like _ARTICLE _NOUN" for different things, often. They are not completely fungible.

**It seems a shame to drive all the way from Trier to Rome, only to turn right around, without having a chance to see any of the sights.**

One could not say "seems like a shame" or "seems to be a shame".

**Not sure why your circulator is cutting out. It seems to be the circuit board.**

One could not say "it seems the circuit board", though one might possibly say "it seems like the circuit board."

**Great, a keg! Now it seems like a party.**

One could not say "now it seems to be a party" there, though one might possibly say "now it seems a party."

Conclusion: *crude* frequency comparisons that combine disparate, non-interchangeable contexts seem like a waste of time, seem to be a waste of time, and seem a waste of time.

P.S. *Like* will sometimes be a stand-in for "to be" and sometimes will be a stand-in for "as though".

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, I still don't understand why `One could not say "seems like a shame" or "seems to be a shame`, `One could not say "it seems the circuit board"`, and `One could not say "now it seems to be a party" there`, so would you please suggest what I should do? Are there any books or resources? Or should I post more questions here on ELL specifically about these counterfactuals?

Comment: *Seems to be* indicates a conjecture.  When the keg of beer arrives, the thirsty party-animal does not jubilantly conjecture "Maybe it's a party."

Comment: Good examples (but given this is a *learner's* site, arguably it might be better to include a subject & verb **I'm** in #2).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's fodder for questions.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo To me, a learner, the answer seems to aim at baffling learners. The answer doesn't explain why "One could not say "seems like a shame" or "seems to be a shame". Does it have to do with the semantics or syntax? It's a mystery. I'm sure it could have been explained better.

Comment: @user1425 "seems like a shame" = *resembles* a shame.  "seems to be a shame" = I *conjecture* that it is a shame.  "seems a shame (to me)" = It is a shame, *in my opinion*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're asking about "seem"..... But if you are....

I would say that "seem" is copular when used with "like". I don't take that to mean it can't stand by itself in other contexts.

He seems a nice enough fellow.

It seems warm in here.

It seems to me you are making this too difficult.

But no, you don't put it next to a noun. You wouldn't say:
He seems baby. She seems secretary. The dog seems poodle.

As for "like":
Yes, it is a preposition, and yes, it is a conjunction. The one site says "strictly speaking". The other site shows by example that this strict distinction is not observed in actual modern speech.  The use of "like" in the sense of "as" has been accepted for about 40 years in US.

"Lucky Strike tastes good—like a cigarette should."  The prescriptivist, "strictly speaking", would insist on  "Lucky Strike tastes good—AS a cigarette should."  But that battle was lost decades ago. Common usage won out over strict rule. The language evolves.

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean saying this: "You wouldn't say: He seems baby." Do you mean that "He seems a baby." is also wrong?