# 'to seem like' : Part of speech and significance of 'like'?

Tags: verbs

What are the import and meaning  of **like** in 'to seem **like**' ? (https://english.stackexchange.com/a/11324/50720 is mute on this.) Why is **like** necessary? 'seem' alone already means:

> [seem](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seem) [no object]  = 1. Give the impression of being something or having a particular quality

Based on http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm, I guess that **like** here is a preposition and not a conjunction? How do you determine/deduce this rigorously?

> Strictly speaking, the word **like** is a preposition, not a conjunction

Obiter dictum: I focus on 'to seem like' here, compared with this question on [the differences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/47620/8712).

Comment: Can you provide some example sentences with **seem like** that you want to analyze? You ask "why is **like** necessary", but provide no examples. Why is it necessary where?

Comment: @CopperKettle Thanks. I'll try to find some reputable examples; please allow me a few days.

Comment: My guess is that you mean something like: "It seems like you already know this."  in which the *like* could be dropped to get: "It seems you already know this."

Comment: You should check "import" (rare)  and "mute" in the dictionary. "like" is also used for "as if".

Answer (score 1):

Normally a sentence is not just "to seem like" but in this case the like, means to be similar to. For example "to seem similar" would mean the same thing. As I said this is not a complete sentence. It may be used as such: The situation seems like it is under control.

Comment: Did this help you?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's a matter of grammar - seems (:)) more like semantics to me.

**Like** would be employed when it's actually like something (a noun).

(1) (it) *Seems like* the car.

vs

(2) (it) *Seems* the car has broken down.

In my limited opinion, the first usage would focus on the thing. The second usage would focus more on the adjective or verb, etc - the state of the thing.

Of course you can say

(3) (it) *Seems like* the car has broken down.

But the emphasis still feels closer to talking about the car, rather than describing what's happened to it. Hope that helps.

This is just intuitive for me - happy if someone can counter example this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually "like" is an adjective used with a complement as in :

- They are as like as two peas (in a pod).
- One pea is like the other / One pea seems like the other.

"like" can also be seen as a preposition as in

- a man like a bear - though it is still an adjektive.

"like" has extended its uses to the detriment os "as" and is often used as a conjunction, pushing back "as". Obviously people find it not practical to distinguish between "like" and "as".